# One radio button which is in div along with label should change three colors based on three different button clicks

Tags: javascript, angular, angular10

I have a radio button in div tag and I have three buttons like start, Inprogress and stop. Based on the button click the radio button should change the color to yellow green and red respectively. I cannot get any inputs for this.

One radio button which is in div along with label should change three colors based on three different button clicks.

Comment: Each Angular component has variables. The buttons set the variable, each to a certain value. And the radio button's style then uses that variable to set the color.

Comment: Hello @ChrisG,  I am confused, Is it possible to provide a fiddle or demo, to make it clear

Comment: Yes, here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5gcvk7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts (note that this is all pretty basic, and part of the docs)

Comment: Very thanks, but here it is changing the color of <div>, But I need to change to the radio button colour. @ChrisG

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? A radio button is a grey circle, it doesn't have a color.

Comment: @Prasannakantheti You would need to use custom CSS to change the color of the radio buttons from the browser's default styling. There are lots and lots of ways to do this: https://www.sliderrevolution.com/resources/styling-radio-buttons/

Comment: Let me explain you @ChirsG , Actually, I have three divs and each div is with radio button and when I select the div , I dont to want to change the div background colour, I need that grey circle to be filled with colors based on the buttons clicked.

Comment: Ok, so this is basically not an Angular but a CSS question.

Comment: Oh Okay, Do you know any way to do in the CSS? - @ChrisG